# Pandoc caption for code blocks

Tags: captions, labels, code, pandoc

Consider the following code block:

```
~~~~{.Python .numberLines caption="test"}
def myfunction(var):
  """ Oh how awesome this is. """
  pass
~~~~
```

The code gets formatted correctly in the Pdf, but the caption does not appear.
I also want to reference to the code block - but how?
Can somebody give me a working example?

Answer (score 15):

Nevermind, I found a way to do it.
I was using the builtin code highlighter.

Setting the `--listings` flag, I can switch to the *lstlistings* package and use the following syntax:

```
~~~~{caption="The preprocessing step" label=lstpreprocess}
def myfunction(var):
  """ Oh how awesome this is. """
  pass
~~~~
```

Pandoc is awesome.

Comment: Is it also possible to number these lines?

Comment: You could try `numbers=left` as a parameter. Did not test that, though.