# pandoc --listings breaks styling of code block

Tags: pdftex, listings, pandoc

Considering this input file:

```
~~~{.html caption="test caption"}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Store</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
~~~

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

When I run command:

```
pandoc ./DOC.md -o ./doc.pdf
```

Listing has nice stylings:

[image: styled lysting]

I want to have also listing captions. So a
[lot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127163/180369)
[of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54025234/3708596)
[people](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/673#issuecomment-23091826) suggest to use `--listings` package.

But after I run

```
pandoc ./DOC.md -o ./doc.pdf --listings
```

The output file is missing styles for code block!

[image]

How to configure pandoc to have nice styles of code block and caption at the same time?

Comment: do you have the `listings` package included in the `*.tex` file?

Comment: No, but I just tried and no luck, still the same results. I've added this header `pandoc -H ./template.tex ./DOC.md -o ./doc.pdf --listings` and `template.tex` contains only `\usepackage{listings}`.

Comment: please provide a full minimal working example, that reproduces your problem.

Comment: This is full example. There is no more code than I provided in question.

Comment: you do have the package installed on your system correctly?

Comment: I have no idea. How to check if it is installed on my system? Usually, if I did not have package installed pandoc throws an error, here is not complaining.

Comment: run `kpsewhich listings.sty` from the shell. if no error is thrown, it's installed properly and the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: Yes I have it installed `kpsewhich listings.sty` produce
`/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty`

Comment: The `listings` output you have posted isn't missing syntax highlighting. The highlighting is just different, i.e. it is monochrome, roman font and uses bold font for keywords. You can customize the output of listings to fit your needs, here is a good starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99638/29873

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of adding captions to code blocks is by using [`pandoc-crossref`](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref):

```
~~~{#lst:captionAttr .html caption="test caption"}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Store</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
~~~


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

Invoke `pandoc` with `pandoc-crossref` as a filter:

```
$  pandoc --filter pandoc-crossref doc.md -o doc.pdf
```

[image]

---

Another way would be to use an existing color scheme for `listings`. There is an implementation of the [solarized theme](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/) from which you could start:

1. Get the package from github: https://github.com/jez/latex-solarized
2. Tell `pandoc` to include the package in the LaTeX preamble by adding a YAML block:

```
---
header-includes: \usepackage{solarized-light}
---
```

resulting in

```
---
header-includes: \usepackage{solarized-light}
---

~~~{.html caption="test caption"}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Store</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
~~~

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

3. Run `pandoc`:

```
$ pandoc --listings doc.md -o doc.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: sounds like you could also provide a custom highlighting style with `\lstset{}`

Comment: @naphaneal Exactly, that is what the `solarized` package for `listings` is doing. You can take the color definitions found there and tweak them to match your preferred highlighting style. Or just search on this site, there are nice examples too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99638/29873

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it turns out that some style was missing for `--listings` option. I copied parts of the logic from `eisvogel.latex` template and added some custom styling over it.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\passthrough}[1]{#1}  % required from pandoc to provide inline

\usepackage{xcolor}   % custom colors

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    %numbers=left,    % I recommend disabling this, as one can use .numberLines in markdown
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

% if you want to use cleveref
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % must come after hyperref package

\crefname{listing}{code}{codes}
\Crefname{listing}{Code}{Codes}
```

and the following works fine:

```
~~~{label=lst:captionAttr .html .numberLines caption="test caption"}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Store</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
~~~

Referencing [@Lst:captionAttr] using cleveref.
```

Feel free to test in the Pandoc template for Legrand Orange Book: https://github.com/igormcoelho/pandoc-template-legrand-orange-book

`pandoc --listings -s -F pandoc-crossref --citeproc --template=orangelegrand.latex book.md -o book.pdf`